# Windows batch script to check duplicates between an UNC path and local dir and delete them from the later

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I want to delete all **today's** files in a local folder that **already** **exist** in a network path (UNC). I've run a batch including below commands but can't say it works properly.

```
@echo off
pushd \\server\archive
forfiles /p "PDF" /s /m "*.pdf" /d +0 /c "cmd /c del C:\Users\user\Desktop\F1\@file"
popd
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you run the command?

Comment: At first, i tested echo instead of del to list the .pdf files that already exist in both folders, but it echoes some random .pdf's that only exist in server's dir.

Comment: can soemone look into this? Thanks https://superuser.com/questions/1415868/batch-scripting-how-to-code-a-unc-path-and-set-it-on-a-directory-variable